# How to make horizontal scrollview in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i've been trying to make a horizontal scrollview but it won't work for two or more widget...instead it will automatically convert them( the widget) to a kind of an ASCII characters

**main.py**

```
#...neccessary modules imported

class Root( BoxLayout ):
    pass


class MainApp( MDApp ):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

then inside the **main.kv** file, i got

```
Root
<Root>:
    orientation:"vertical"

    ScrollView:
       do_scroll_x: True
       do_scroll_y: False 

       BoxLayout:
          size_hint:None, None
          width:self.minimum_width
          spacing:dp(20)

          # Then follows repetition of the below widget 20 times
          MDCard:
            MDLabel:
              text:"some text"
```

it wont show the widget but some random Ascii characters

Answer (score 1):

You have to give some `size` to the contents of the `BoxLayout`:

```py
            # Then follows repetition of the below widget 20 times
            MDCard:
                size_hint:None, None
                size: dp(100), dp(50)
                MDLabel:
                    text:"some text"
```